# Textures look fine in edit mode but go crazy in object mode

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv, edit-mode, object-mode

Hi I'm trying to add a wood&paint texture to my house but when I try that blender goes a little crazy. I'm pretty new to Blender btw.

I added a texture from Poliigon, smart UV projected my house and applied the texture. In edit mode it looks reasonable but when I leave edit mode every face gets rotated weirdly like in the picture.

The house has a couple of modifiers:

1. Displace (to make the planks look old)
2. Solidify (giving the planks thickness)
3. Boolean (intersect for the roof)
4. Boolean (difference for the windows and doors)

Edit mode view:

[image: edit mode]

Object mode view:

[image: object mode]

Shader:

[image: shader]

Mesh:

[image: mesh]

Can anyone help me with what's going wrong here?

edit: I've tried applying the modifiers in different orders, re-unwrapping the mesh after that but that didn't work. I also tried adding horizontal seams across the mesh but that made no change either.

Comment: Try applying or disabling different modifiers to see if that changes how the texture is projected.

Comment: This doesn't work, even if I UV unwrap it again. I've also tried adding horizontal seams to the mesh but that didn't change anything either.

Comment: Maybe there are overlapping faces? Have you check the normal face orientation? Make sure its all blue. And try to apply the rotation scale. If you don't mind, maybe I can take a look the blend file.

Comment: @YogiSeptiargy Nope the mesh is all good :/